# Rails 3 routing constraints don't seem to be matching the regex properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am using Rails 3.0.5 and I have setup a route using a regex constraint. It used to work on Rails 2.3.5, but it's not working in Rails 3. The route looks like this:

```
get '/:version_id' => 'pastes#show', :constraints => { :version_id => /[\d\w]{40}/ }
```

It doesn't work at all. However, the following work:

```
get '/:version_id' => 'pastes#show', :constraints => { :version_id => /.{40}/ }

get '/:version_id' => 'pastes#show', :constraints => { :version_id => /\w{40}/ }

get '/:version_id' => 'pastes#show'
```

Is there something wrong with the way Rails handles [ ] matching? or am I doing something wrong?

version_id usually looks something like this:

```
816616001d7ce848944a9e0d71a5a22d3b546943
```

Comment: Is this get declaration nested somewhere or is it a top-level declaration? I.e how do you call your example? Does localhost:3000/816616001d7ce848944a9e0d71a5a22d3b546943 - work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a solution as to why one may not work over the other.

However, according to the PickAxe book, `\w` is actually a superset of `\d`.

```
\w  [A-Za-z0-9\_]   ASCII word character
\d        [0-9]     ASCII decimal digit character
```

Therefore, `[\d\w]{40}` is no different from `\w{40}`, which works for you.